# Why there is no verilog code of other module except ProgramCounter generated by chisel?

Tags: verilog, riscv, chisel, register-transfer-level, riscv32

I'm writing a chisel project as follows: [Chisel Project](https://github.com/wuliJerry/ysyx-workbench/tree/pa2/npc). When I tried to generate a verilog file by

```scala
object Elaborate extends App {
  (new chisel3.stage.ChiselStage).execute(args, Seq(chisel3.stage.ChiselGeneratorAnnotation(() =>new Top())))
}
```

and the command:

```bash
mill -i __.test.runMain Elaborate -td $(BUILD_DIR)
```

it generated a verilog file:

```
module ProgramCounter(
  input         clock,
  input         reset,
  output [63:0] io_nowAdd
);
`ifdef RANDOMIZE_REG_INIT
  reg [63:0] _RAND_0;
`endif // RANDOMIZE_REG_INIT
  reg [63:0] cntReg; // @[ProgramCounter.scala 12:23]
  wire [63:0] _cntReg_T_2 = cntReg + 64'h4; // @[ProgramCounter.scala 13:65]
  assign io_nowAdd = cntReg; // @[ProgramCounter.scala 15:13]
  always @(posedge clock) begin
    if (reset) begin // @[ProgramCounter.scala 12:23]
      cntReg <= 64'h80000000; // @[ProgramCounter.scala 12:23]
    end else if (cntReg == 64'h8fffffff) begin // @[ProgramCounter.scala 13:16]
      cntReg <= 64'h80000000;
    end else begin
      cntReg <= _cntReg_T_2;
    end
  end
// Register and memory initialization
`ifdef RANDOMIZE_GARBAGE_ASSIGN
`define RANDOMIZE
`endif
`ifdef RANDOMIZE_INVALID_ASSIGN
`define RANDOMIZE
`endif
`ifdef RANDOMIZE_REG_INIT
`define RANDOMIZE
`endif
`ifdef RANDOMIZE_MEM_INIT
`define RANDOMIZE
`endif
`ifndef RANDOM
`define RANDOM $random
`endif
`ifdef RANDOMIZE_MEM_INIT
  integer initvar;
`endif
`ifndef SYNTHESIS
`ifdef FIRRTL_BEFORE_INITIAL
`FIRRTL_BEFORE_INITIAL
`endif
initial begin
  `ifdef RANDOMIZE
    `ifdef INIT_RANDOM
      `INIT_RANDOM
    `endif
    `ifndef VERILATOR
      `ifdef RANDOMIZE_DELAY
        #`RANDOMIZE_DELAY begin end
      `else
        #0.002 begin end
      `endif
    `endif
`ifdef RANDOMIZE_REG_INIT
  _RAND_0 = {2{`RANDOM}};
  cntReg = _RAND_0[63:0];
`endif // RANDOMIZE_REG_INIT
  `endif // RANDOMIZE
end // initial
`ifdef FIRRTL_AFTER_INITIAL
`FIRRTL_AFTER_INITIAL
`endif
`endif // SYNTHESIS
endmodule
module Top(
  input         clock,
  input         reset,
  output [63:0] io_pcAddr,
  input  [31:0] io_inst
);
  wire  PC_clock; // @[Top.scala 14:18]
  wire  PC_reset; // @[Top.scala 14:18]
  wire [63:0] PC_io_nowAdd; // @[Top.scala 14:18]
  ProgramCounter PC ( // @[Top.scala 14:18]
    .clock(PC_clock),
    .reset(PC_reset),
    .io_nowAdd(PC_io_nowAdd)
  );
  assign io_pcAddr = PC_io_nowAdd; // @[Top.scala 18:13]
  assign PC_clock = clock;
  assign PC_reset = reset;
endmodule
```

which has nothing to do with other modules except `ProgramCounter`. While I checked the `Top.fir` file on which the verilog was based, it shows:

```
circuit Top :
  module ProgramCounter :
    input clock : Clock
    input reset : Reset
    output io : { nowAdd : UInt<64>}

    reg cntReg : UInt<64>, clock with :
      reset => (reset, UInt<64>("h80000000")) @[ProgramCounter.scala 12:23]
    node _cntReg_T = eq(cntReg, UInt<32>("h8fffffff")) @[ProgramCounter.scala 13:24]
    node _cntReg_T_1 = add(cntReg, UInt<3>("h4")) @[ProgramCounter.scala 13:65]
    node _cntReg_T_2 = tail(_cntReg_T_1, 1) @[ProgramCounter.scala 13:65]
    node _cntReg_T_3 = mux(_cntReg_T, UInt<32>("h80000000"), _cntReg_T_2) @[ProgramCounter.scala 13:16]
    cntReg <= _cntReg_T_3 @[ProgramCounter.scala 13:10]
    io.nowAdd <= cntReg @[ProgramCounter.scala 15:13]

  module Register :
    input clock : Clock
    input reset : Reset
    output io : { flip src1Idx : UInt<5>, flip src2Idx : UInt<5>, src1Data : UInt<64>, src2Data : UInt<64>, flip writeEnable : UInt<1>, flip regWriteIdx : UInt<5>, flip writeDate : UInt<64>}

    wire _registerFile_WIRE : UInt<64>[32] @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[0] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[1] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[2] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[3] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[4] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[5] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[6] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[7] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[8] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[9] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[10] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[11] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[12] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[13] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[14] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[15] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[16] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[17] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[18] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[19] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[20] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[21] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[22] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[23] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[24] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[25] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[26] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[27] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[28] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[29] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[30] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    _registerFile_WIRE[31] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 25:37]
    reg registerFile : UInt<64>[32], clock with :
      reset => (reset, _registerFile_WIRE) @[Register.scala 25:29]
    registerFile[0] <= UInt<64>("h0") @[Register.scala 28:19]
    io.src1Data <= registerFile[io.src1Idx] @[Register.scala 30:15]
    io.src2Data <= registerFile[io.src2Idx] @[Register.scala 31:15]
    node _registerFile_T = neq(io.regWriteIdx, UInt<1>("h0")) @[Register.scala 33:72]
    node _registerFile_T_1 = and(io.writeEnable, _registerFile_T) @[Register.scala 33:54]
    node _registerFile_T_2 = mux(_registerFile_T_1, io.writeDate, registerFile[io.regWriteIdx]) @[Register.scala 33:38]
    registerFile[io.regWriteIdx] <= _registerFile_T_2 @[Register.scala 33:32]

  module InstructionDecoder :
    input clock : Clock
    input reset : Reset
    output io : { flip inst : UInt<32>, srcRegOne : UInt<5>, srcRegTwo : UInt, distanceReg : UInt<5>}

    node _io_srcRegOne_T = bits(io.inst, 19, 15) @[InstuctionDecoder.scala 16:26]
    io.srcRegOne <= _io_srcRegOne_T @[InstuctionDecoder.scala 16:16]
    node _io_srcRegTwo_T = bits(io.inst, 31, 20) @[InstuctionDecoder.scala 17:26]
    io.srcRegTwo <= _io_srcRegTwo_T @[InstuctionDecoder.scala 17:16]
    node _io_distanceReg_T = bits(io.inst, 11, 7) @[InstuctionDecoder.scala 18:28]
    io.distanceReg <= _io_distanceReg_T @[InstuctionDecoder.scala 18:18]

  module Adder :
    input clock : Clock
    input reset : Reset
    output io : { flip dataOne : UInt<64>, flip dateTwo : UInt<64>, flip subOrAdd : UInt<1>, dataOut : UInt<64>}

    node _io_dataOut_T = sub(io.dataOne, io.dateTwo) @[Adder.scala 17:45]
    node _io_dataOut_T_1 = tail(_io_dataOut_T, 1) @[Adder.scala 17:45]
    node _io_dataOut_T_2 = add(io.dataOne, io.dateTwo) @[Adder.scala 17:70]
    node _io_dataOut_T_3 = tail(_io_dataOut_T_2, 1) @[Adder.scala 17:70]
    node _io_dataOut_T_4 = mux(io.subOrAdd, _io_dataOut_T_1, _io_dataOut_T_3) @[Adder.scala 17:20]
    io.dataOut <= _io_dataOut_T_4 @[Adder.scala 17:14]

  module Top :
    input clock : Clock
    input reset : UInt<1>
    output io : { pcAddr : UInt<64>, flip inst : UInt<32>}

    inst PC of ProgramCounter @[Top.scala 14:18]
    PC.clock <= clock
    PC.reset <= reset
    inst Reg of Register @[Top.scala 15:19]
    Reg.clock <= clock
    Reg.reset <= reset
    inst Decoder of InstructionDecoder @[Top.scala 16:23]
    Decoder.clock <= clock
    Decoder.reset <= reset
    inst adder of Adder @[Top.scala 17:21]
    adder.clock <= clock
    adder.reset <= reset
    io.pcAddr <= PC.io.nowAdd @[Top.scala 18:13]
    Decoder.io.inst <= io.inst @[Top.scala 19:19]
    Reg.io.regWriteIdx <= Decoder.io.distanceReg @[Top.scala 21:22]
    Reg.io.writeEnable <= UInt<1>("h1") @[Top.scala 22:22]
    Reg.io.src1Idx <= Decoder.io.srcRegOne @[Top.scala 24:18]
    Reg.io.src2Idx <= UInt<1>("h0") @[Top.scala 25:18]
    adder.io.dataOne <= Reg.io.src1Data @[Top.scala 27:20]
    adder.io.dateTwo <= Decoder.io.srcRegTwo @[Top.scala 28:20]
    Reg.io.writeDate <= adder.io.dataOut @[Top.scala 30:20]
    adder.io.subOrAdd <= UInt<1>("h0") @[Top.scala 31:21]
```

The other project can be seen in its content, so why did verilog file missing them?

Comment: Please give at least your Chisel module source.

Comment: Sorry, but I've offered it at the link in the first line. Is that inaccessible?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the externally visible behavior of your circuit does not depend on any of the other modules. By *externally visible behavior* I mean the values of the toplevel output (`io_nowAdd` in your case) as well as any `printf` or `assert` statements (you do not have any in your circuit).

If you want to prevent the compiler from removing such unused signals, you can use the `dontTouch` function on any signal you would like to retain.